# Always call a method when loading hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate

The project I'm working on uses Hibernate for persistence.

The project is split in sub-projects, four of which are relevant here:

- message-dom
- user-service
- message-service
- case-service

The Message entity (in user-dom) contains a `String userID` field, and an `@Transient String userName` field. Another entity, Case, has a OneToOne relation with Message. The problem is the following:

- Everytime we load a Message (either directly, in the message-service, or indirectly by loading a Case in the case-service), we need to set its userName field.
- The userName is retrieved by calling the user-service.
- The user-service can't be called from message-dom (for dependency reasons).

I've seen there is a `@PostLoad` annotation for entities, but clearly these won't help here since we can't call the service from the entity. Currently we do the service call by hand, but this is error prone (especially when loading a Message indirectly inside a Case).

How can we ensure that the field gets set everytime a Message entity is loaded ?

Comment: implement Postload event and register it on the configuration object

Comment: @Firo : Could you elaborate a bit please ? This seems to go in the right direction, but I don't know what the config object is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the end application where all parts come together implement `org.hibernate.event.PostLoadEventListener` and add it via xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        ...
        <event type="load">
            <listener class="com.eg.MyPostLoadListener"/>
            <listener class="org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPostLoadEventListener"/>
        </event>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

or via code

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
PostLoadEventListener[] stack = { new MyPostLoadListener(), new DefaultPostLoadEventListener() };
cfg.EventListeners().setPostLoadEventListeners(stack);
```

Comment: +1. Just: vote for `xml` configuration to support easier extending later